# Routing error for create action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

Iam new to rails ,Iam getting the above error don't know why.i have a link from where Iam getting values and storing in controller

```
    <%= link_to "Add Stocks " ,userstocks_path(user: 
    current_user,short_code: @stock.short_code,stock_id: @stock.id ? 
    @stock.id : '' ),class: "btn btn-primary"%>
```

my controller create action

```
 def create
     if params[:stock_id].present?
     @userstock = Userstock.new(stock_id: params[:stock_id],user: current_user)
      end            
   respond_to do |format|
   if @userstock.save
    format.html { redirect_to users_my_portfolio_path   , notice: 'Userstock was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @userstock }
  end
 end
end
```

my routes

```
    resources :userstocks,except: [:show,:edit,:update,:index]
```

Instead of going to post request in userstocks_path its going to index of userstocks_path .and if the remove "except: :index" from routes its giving me template error in console .any solutions

Comment: Did you try with `new_userstock_path` instead `userstocks_path`, or to what method do you want to make a request?

Comment: actually userstock is a scaffold in which I dont require form.just wanna use create action in userstocks controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reason being you need to define method type with `link_to` as per REST index(method type is 'get') and create(method type is 'post') action both has same routes but the difference is their method type. your can see it by command `rake routes | grep userstocks`

try this -

```
<%= link_to "Add Stocks " ,userstocks_path(user: 
    current_user,short_code: @stock.short_code,stock_id: @stock.id ? 
    @stock.id : '' ),:method=> :post, class: "btn btn-primary"%>
```

thank you.